# Switching between active RDP's via Reminna (How-To)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I often use RDP to remotely connect Windows servers & SSH to linux distro(s).

As the subject explains; I always wondered how to to switch between active RDP windows. I'm using the default client **Remmina** as it serves my purpose very well. But the only problem is that, I'm lost when I need to switch active windows in between. To make this more clear;

> When I RDP to windows pc1, it connects perfectly. And then when I connect to windows pc2 whilst having pc1, yes it indeed connects as the same. But, soon after when I try to check for an option to switch between those two, I'm lost. Doesn't matter how many RDP sessions I make as it connects to the requested server perfectly. Despite having many connected windows, I always need to close each and every connected sessions to go back to the other active session.

**P.S.:** Though it looks simple, I don't want to keep on connecting to each machines multiple times by closing it. My requirement is to switch active windows without having to close and connect again. I'm sure there'll be a way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a quick update. After searching through few source I figured it out for my self. It looks bit idiotic for me as I didn't notice (since I was using a full screen) that there's a screen toggle option to switch in between (seen below).

[image]

Also, what I found is shortcut key which make it more easier not click on the toggle icon.

- Hold <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> / <kbd>></kbd> (left/right arrow keys) to switch between active screens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't realise that Remmina had this capability either - even though I've been using it for years . Granted I probably didn't read the manual fully, but it does seem to me that Remmina is a  very useful piece of software,  though it isn't particularly intuitive. It has also become very stable over the years.  Your answer states that the "Right Control" key can be used, but perhaps you should state this key can be changed in the preferences.

Comment: @DAB - Well, my initiative was to achieve the what I required, if I had the intention to change the key preferences, I would added it as well. But hey, thanks for the tip!